# UNITY || How to access the "exit transitions" of the current played clip from the animator?

Tags: unity, c#, animation, scripting, animator

So, I have an animator , i can access it.
But from there I have no idea how to access the clips inside.
I need to access the transition of the clips.

I got as far as accessing the object of the "Animator" class.

[image]

EDIT:

It appears The TransitionInfo datatype doesnt provide conditions.
I need the conditions!

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to access it via code or in the inspector?

Comment: via code of course :)

Comment: I'm curious why you need to access the transitions themselves. Can you describe what feature this is serving? There might be other ways to achieve your ultimate goal.

Comment: @DMGregory: Its about the transition. 
You see, during the transition the animator is in 2 states at once. And setting the transition time to 0 doesnt help. He is always at least for a very short time in 2 states, which messes with "on state enter" and "on state leave"- since LEAVE is called before enter.

Comment: Can you describe how this causes issues in your game? We might be able to find more straightforward solutions to those issues.

Comment: A "on state enter" instanciates a prefab, which deletes the old prefab, if there is any.
This kinda works if I just let the transition happen in 0.5 sec or something.

But when I make it "too fast" it causes problems like: Too fast transitions after transitions -> loosing those instances... etc.

My solution was using "animator.play(stateName);
But for that I need to know the transition conditions...

Comment: question must clear by first time. else ask correct details in comments.

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat complicated but achievable. This is a list of things you'll need to go through:

1. Give the transition a name in the editor. Let's say you call it
   `"AnimAToAnimB"`.
2. Figure out which layer of the animator the transition is in.
   Let's assume it's in the default `"Base Layer"`.
3. Query the hash code of the transition up-front via code:

   `animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.AnimAToAnimB");`

   and store it in some variable, let's say `transitionAToBHash`.
4. Research "Animator State Machine Behaviours". You'll want one
   attached inside the layer of the transition that you're interested
   in.
5. Implement your own custom StateMachineBehaviour that will be able
   to listen and receive animator state change callbacks. More info:
   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html
6. Once you have your custom state behaviour attached and
   implemented, upon receiving the OnStateExit callback, grab the
   currently active animation transition and compare it to your cached
   transition hash:

---

```
// inside your custom state machine behaviour

override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
{
   var transitionInfo = animator.GetAnimatorTransitionInfo(layerIdOfYourTransitionAToB);

   if (transitionInfo.userNameHash == transitionAToBHash)
   {
      // PROFIT! your transition "transitionAToB" has just started!
   }   
}
```

Note: it can get a lot more complicated if you're using things like sub state machines.

Comment: sir youre awesome. 
I actually gave up a while ago... I thought its unachiveable since I read a 3-pages long forumpost about this particular problem.

Comment: Whops... i have to take the "correct answer" back... I mean. Yeah i get the info, but i dont have access to those conditions inside that particular transition.

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what do you mean by "I don't have access to those conditions"?

Comment: Allright, i updated my question

Comment: In theory it's still doable, but the solution wouldn't be pretty nor very maintainable. You'd have to write an editor script that would grab your AnimatorController, walk all of it's transitions, as shown here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/find-all-animator-transitions.473779/, access the conditions inside AnimatorState.transitions and then create a dictionary that would map transitionHash -> yourOwnConditionStruct and eventually pass that dictionary to a game object that's interested in knowing transition conditions. Also, you'd have to run this script every time transitions change.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code to call the animation using script

```
public Animator Anim;
void Start(){
    Anim.Play("Animation_Clip_Name");
}
//Trigger it by button click or inside other functions to change the animation.
public void NextAnimation()
{
   Anim.Play("Next_Animation_Name");
}
```

Comment: yeah thats not the question here